# Is it legal to secretly buy your employer's factory?

Tags: employee

An EU factory manager is offered an opportunity to purchase the building from which his employer's business operates. He buys it and says nothing to his employer about his intention before actually becoming the new owner.

By secretly becoming his employer's landlord, surely the manager now has the capacity to further increase his powers within his employer's business. For example, he may threaten to increase the rent unless he is given more freedom in relation to commercial decisions of the business. Or he may demand a stake in the business in exchange for security of tenure on the premises. In the extreme he may force the existing business out of the building entirely.

But can his employer, upon learning the identity of the new premises owner, fire the manager for breach of trust in the implied terms of his contract as his acquisition of the business premises effectively makes him a partner in the business ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be considered a breach of fiduciary duty.  The Cornell Legal Information Institute, for example, [defines the Duty of Loyalty](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/duty_of_loyalty) as:

> The duty of loyalty stands for the principle that directors and officers of a corporation in making all decisions in their capacities as corporate fiduciaries, must act without personal economic conflict. The duty of loyalty can be breached either by making a self-interested transaction or taking a corporate opportunity.

It appears that using his dual roles as the company’s landlord and its manager to negotiate a better deal for himself at his employer’s expense, would breach that.

It’s difficult to see how the manager/landlord would be able to avoid taking advantage of the situation, even if he tried.  For instance, would the company be able to replace him as manager if they knew he would then evict them in his capacity as landlord?

The purchase itself might breach rules as well.  This might, depending on circumstances, fall under the doctrine of a [corporate opportunity](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/Corporate_opportunity):

> ". . . a corporate officer or director may not take a business opportunity for his own if: (1) the corporation is financially able to exploit the opportunity; (2) the opportunity is within the corporation's line of business; (3) the corporation has an interest or expectancy in the opportunity; and (4) by taking the opportunity for his own, the corporate fiduciary will thereby be placed in a position inimicable to his duties to the corporation. The Court in Guth also derived a corollary which states that a director or officer may take a corporate opportunity if: (1) the opportunity is presented to the director or officer in his individual and not his corporate capacity; (2) the opportunity is not essential to the corporation; (3) the corporation holds no interest or expectancy in the opportunity; and (4) the director or officer has not wrongfully employed the resources of the corporation in pursuing or exploiting the opportunity. Guth, 5 A.2d at 509."

Comment: Interesting, the second factor. By taking for himself an opportunity that his company would benefit from in order to further his own ambitions the manager has failed to act in the best interests of the company - something that is his primary responsibility.

Comment: There is no breach of fiduciary duty at all. Merely becoming able to corner the employer falls short of taking advantage of that ability. The OP's description only portrays that the employee attained that ability, not that he is applying it.

Comment: @Davislor  Clearly, if the employee remains an employee and denies an opportunity to his employer in favor of setting up his own company (with others) to exploit that opportunity then we have a "corporate opportunity" situation. A court would ask the question of why a young manager would outlay significant funds (or secure loans) to acquire a premises if he had no more prospect of benefit than that arising from another real estate venture ? And if better ventures were available to the manager, a court may conclude that another - as yet unrealised - benefit pertained to his factory purchase.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I’ve edited the response into my question.

Answer (score 1):

> can his employer - and new tenant - upon learning the identity of the new premises owner, fire the manager for breach of trust in the implied terms of his contract ?

It is lawful for the employer to terminate the employment relation. Also note that there is no breach of the implied terms of that contract. A breach has to do with a party's actions that conclusively --rather than potentially-- contravene the contract. Your description only reflects that the employee now has "*the capacity to further increase his powers*" on the employer, not that the employee actually is taking advantage of his new status as landlord.

Labor laws in jurisdictions of the EU purport to compensate the imbalance from the greater bargaining power an employer typically has over the employee. However, the unusual premise that at some point an employee manages to become his employer's landlord weakens or strikes a presumption of said imbalance. Accordingly, treating the matter as an *inter pares* scenario is more appropriate than when a clear imbalance exists.

The employee's new status as employer's landlord reasonably disrupts the set of basic assumptions with which an employer makes his hiring decisions. A party has no obligation to accept the new risks that the counterparty deliberately creates after their contract was formed.

Comment: But in the EU could an employer summarily disengage an employee on the last paragraph grounds ? Can the employee not argue that no *actual* imbalance in the company-manager relationship has **yet** occurred ? Although the threat of such a dismissal by the company could be a good bargaining chip in getting the manager to sell the premises to the company, surely the relationship of trust between company and its managers has been irreparably damaged ?

Comment: @Trunk "*no actual imbalance in the company-manager relationship has yet occurred*". By alleging that, the employee impliedly concedes that the legislative protections against that sort of imbalance are inapplicable here. "*could be a good bargaining chip in getting the manager to sell the premises to the company*". Not clear why someone who owns enough real estate to be the employer's landlord would need to keep his job there. "*surely the relationship of trust between company and its managers has been irreparably damaged ?*" That is too speculative and not about legal matters.

Comment: Factory buildings in the period were quite crude and it was a small factory - anyone with ownership of his own home could remortgage it to raise most of the loan. Even without loanee collateral, the lender would have the deeds of the factory building itself as security till the loan payments were well in hand. It is likely that the factory's bank manager was complicit in the plan as it would advance the expansion plans of the factory manager - something in the bank's interest and something the elderly factory's owner was against due to the financial risk involved.

Comment: It's a fine legal point but I don't know if asserting that no actual imbalance had occurred since the premises acquisition implies acceptance of there ever being one. If relationship of trust is too vague here, then take the reality of the manager's conflict of interest between maximizing his rental income as a landlord versus his duty to minimize all input costs, including premises rent, for his employer's company. Also consider his role as factory manager along with his statutory obligations to provide a safe and decent workplace to employees of his tenant - all expenses to his tenant/boss.

Comment: @Trunk "*It is likely that the factory's bank manager was complicit in the plan*". Again, that is too speculative, and coupled with your added thoughts on collateral, deeds, etc. is bringing your post back to its previous convoluted state. "*implies acceptance of there ever being one.*" There being *one* what? "*take the reality of the manager's conflict of interest*" The last paragraph of the answer addresses the risk of employee's conflict of interest.

Comment: But this is background - not part of the essential legal question. **You** asked why a factory owner still needed a salary if he owned a factory. I explained plausibly how the factory was acquired. Clearly rent on a small run-down factory is much less than his salary, so he must keep the day-job. Asserting that no actual imbalance [in the company-manager relationship] had occurred since the premises acquisition implies acceptance of there ever being [an imbalance in the company-manager relationship].

Comment: @Trunk "*Clearly rent on a small run-down factory is much less than his salary, so he must keep the day-job.*" It wasn't clear that the factory is a "small run-down" one, but your comparison of salary vs. rent defeats your premise that the acquisition helps the employee+landlord "*further increase his powers within his employer's business*". Regardless, the point is that it is lawful for the employer to terminate him. No need for going in circles by indefinitely adding possible details.

Comment: Paying down so much a month more for a premises loan does **not** defeat the assertion that his power over his employer has been increased since that purchase. (How could it ?) It simply means that he has less disposable income due to a loan to buy his employer's premises - a premises whose ownership gives him greater consideration from his employer in any dealings between them and which is a relatively secure investment. Are you saying that just because US employers may terminate you at will that the same disregard for fairness in dismissal applies here in EU ? In EU you can't fire at will.

Comment: And if you say the employer may terminate the employee described above for his actions in buying the premises, please state why precisely IYHO. I note that you are no more a practising lawyer than I am. Perhaps the tone of your comments might be adjusted for this reality. I came to SE Law for legal opinion of professionals - not amateur viewpoints.

Comment: @Trunk "*Are you saying that just because US employers may terminate you at will that the same disregard for fairness in dismissal applies here in EU ?*" No. Not at all. The answer doesn't even mention the US. This has nothing to do with the doctrine of at-will employment, but with the contract law tenet that for a contract to be binding it must have been entered *knowingly and willfully*. "*I came to SE Law for legal opinion of professionals*". Good, find one who is willing to cope with the endless details you bring up when an answer doesn't spell out what you wish to hear.